# Apache Atlas Delete Created Entity Type "Relationship"

Tags: apache-atlas

Im trying to delete a created Type of Relationship, because my gui isnt working the right way anymore. I created the Relationship with following Post-Request at "/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs"

```
    {
    "relationshipDefs" : [{
        "name":"hub_to_link",
        "typeVersion": "1.0",
        "relationshipCategorgy":"ASSOCIATION",
        "relationshipLabel": "__hub_to.hub_to_link",
        "endDef1": {
            "type": "HUB",
            "name":"fields",
            "isContainer": true,
            "cardinalitity": "SET",
            "isLegacyAttribute": true
        },
        "endDef2": {
            "type": "LINK",
            "name": "event",
            "isContainer": false,
            "cardinalitity": "SINGLE",
            "isLegacyAttribute": true

        }
    }]
}
```

I tried to delete the relationship-type via delete "v2/types/typedefs" and the same code as above.
I tried to delete as following:

```
{
            "category": "RELATIONSHIP",
            "guid": "861dffc5-e63e-45d0-9d09-33dc2e4e4b9b",

}
```

But i keep on getting an empty response or the following:

```
{
    "errorCode": "ATLAS-400-00-030",
    "errorMessage": "ASSOCIATION relationshipDef hub_to_link creation attempted with an end specifying isContainer"
}
```

I tried couple of other payloads too, but it wont work. Any Help or hint is appreciated thanks !